# How to retrieve a JSON array with android annotations?

Tags: java, android, json, android-annotations

I have a web service that sends a JSON similar to this one:

```
[
   "4.11.3",
   "4.10.7",
   "4.10.2",
   "4.9.1"
]
```

My Rest interface looks like this:

```
@Rest(...)
public interface RestInterface {

    @Get("...")
    String[] getVersions();
}
```

But I always get null as return value. Could someone help me please?

Comment: I did not use the REST API before, but i know you have to add a converter. Did you read [this](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API) carefully?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your rest service:

```
@Accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Comment: a short explanation why the code snippet solves the issue, would increase the quality of the response!

Answer (score 0):

your json is a json-array of length 4 containing strings

so .... use following code :

```
JSONArray versionJsonArray=new JSONArray(<web-service response>);
String[] versionString=new String[versionJsonArray.length()];

for(int j=0;j<versionJsonArray.length();j++)
    versionString[j]=versionJsonArray.getString(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Rest(...)
public interface RestInterface {

@Get("...")
    JSONArray getVersions();
}
```

let the rest adapter type the string into a json array.